# python+pip install bson error

Tags: python, pip, bson

i want install 3rd library -> bson.
but error with next, who knows why?

```
# pip install bson
Collecting bson
  Using cached bson-0.5.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-cP7YdW/bson/setup.py", line 8, in <module>
        from pip import get_installed_distributions
    ImportError: cannot import name get_installed_distributions

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-cP7YdW/bson/
```

system info:

```
# uname -a
Linux instance-says 4.9.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.82-1+deb9u3 (2018-03-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

python and pip version info：

```
# python -V
Python 2.7.13
# pip --version
pip 10.0.0 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

Comment: Try: sudo easy_install pip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pip` authors were warning for many years to not [`import pip`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program). Finally at version 10 they restructured their code.

To continue using `pip` with packages that import `pip` you need `pip` version 9:

```
python -m pip install -U 'pip>=9,<10'
```

PS. There is already a [bug report](https://github.com/py-bson/bson/issues/77).

Comment: yet, it's a bug. but failed when I tried to install it like "python -m pip install -U 'pip>=9,<10'". pip version was still on version >=10.

Comment: @lotusecho try `sudo -H python -m pip install -U 'pip>=9,<10'`

Comment: @Laurenz those commands are well work. thanks for all. When trying to solve the problem, I forgot i was in my python virtualenv(pyenv). i just use it like this > /root/.pyenv/shims/python -m pip install -U 'pip>=9,<10' . maybe virtualenv has some bugs with path finding problem.

Answer (score 3):

easy fix:

```
pip uninstall bson
pip uninstall pymongo
pip install pymongo
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip install --upgrade setuptools` and run again.